Writing a Search Excel Formula to Verify a String of Character
Good Evening Everyone,
Dont mean to be a bug. So I am trying to figure out how to write an Excel formula to verify what our finance department have processed and entered onto ORACLE versus what I have sent to our finance department from my Excel invoice tracker. Please see the table and picture provided and attached below.

The challenge is: 1) My own invoice tracker invoice number does not have the same spacing or indentation compared to our Finance department entered onto ORACLE ie ORACLE has 333222 and I have INV - 333222. So ORACLE does not have the INV. 2) Or I entered INV-CC7779990124END on Excel but on ORACLE my finance department personnel entered CC7779990124END (without the INV-) 3) The spacing or the INV is missing on my tracker or on ORACLE's report data.
Is there a way to write an Excel formula that will look/search for both columns and if matches then I can get either a "PAID" vs. "Not Yet Paid" result? I am guessing some sort of SIGMA or SCAN function? Thanks in advance for any help or guidance in this matter!



ORACLE   Report's Invoice Number

My Own Invoice Tracker Number on   Excel

Result (Has This Invoice Been   Paid?)




333222

INV-333222

PAID


444333

INV - 444333

Not Yet Paid


222111

inv - 234567




123456

ROU022024




234567

INV - ROU122023




345678

INV - CC7779990323BEF




INV-123444

INV-CC7779990124END




INV-234555






INV-345667






INV-ROU022024






INV-ROU072023






INV-ROU122023






INV-060708(BEF)






CC7779990524






CC7779990323BEF






CC7779990124END








So as per the result column all should be paid but why is the second one showing not paid? One way: =BYROW(C2:C8,LAMBDA(α, IF(OR(1-ISERR(SEARCH(IFNA(TEXTAFTER(A2:A17,"-"),A2:A17),IFNA(TEXTAFTER(SUBSTITUTE(α," ",),"-"),α)))),"Paid","Not Paid")))

Good morning! @MayukhBhattacharya Please allow me to clarify. So, I submit the invoices to my finance department. You are correct that everything should have been paid. I guess I am using the formula as a way to verify if I have the "backup" documentation in my invoice folder. If I have the backup invoice documentation then my tracker will have the Invoice number :) Thank you!

Solutions are posted you can try and verify !!

@MayukhBhattacharya thank you very much, the formula works! May I trouble you to share with me and teach me: 1) Is there another formula for me to write to put it next to the Results column after your formula gives me either the "Paid" or "Not Paid yet" status. I can get ORACLE Report's version of the Invoice Number? So that way my Invoice Tracker and Oracle report can "relate" or "speak" to each other. My plan is to use a vlookup function after I have ORACLE report's version of the invoice number to search for the payment date from the Oracle report to put it next to MY invoice tracker.

Here is one way of doing this to get the desired output, per context of the OP, all the results should be showing as Paid however not sure why you have given the second one as Not Yet Paid. Additionally, I have added two more examples in MyInvoice range just to ensure that we even get Not Yet Paids as results.


A step-by-step formula, easy to read and debug for future references, however, could make it shorter:
=LET(
     _MyInvoice, C2:C10,
     _Oracle, A2:A17,
     _FixOracle, IFNA(TEXTAFTER(_Oracle,"-"),_Oracle),
     _FixInvoice, IFNA(TEXTAFTER(SUBSTITUTE(_MyInvoice," ",),"-"),_MyInvoice),
     BYROW(_FixInvoice,LAMBDA(α,IF(OR(1-ISERR(SEARCH(_FixOracle,α))),"Paid","Not Yet Paid"))))


Can be achieved without using a LAMBDA() helper function also:
=LET(
     _MyInvoice, IFNA(TRIM(TEXTAFTER(C2:C10,"-")),C2:C10),
     _Oracle, IFNA(TRIM(TEXTAFTER(A2:A17,"-")),A2:A17)&"",
     IF(1-ISNA(XMATCH(_MyInvoice,_Oracle)),"Paid","Not Yet Paid"))



Clean and Match
=LET(source,A2:A17,lookup,C2:C11,
        remove," ",after,"-",yes,"PAID",no,"Not yet paid",
    GetClean,LAMBDA(array,IFERROR(TEXTAFTER(
        SUBSTITUTE(array,remove,""),after),""&array)),
    IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(GetClean(lookup),GetClean(source))),yes,no))


In More Detail
=LET(source,A2:A17,lookup,C2:C11,
        remove," ",after,"-",yes,"PAID",no,"Not yet paid",
    GetClean,LAMBDA(array,IFERROR(TEXTAFTER(
        SUBSTITUTE(array,remove,""),after),""&array)),
    s,GetClean(source),
    l,GetClean(lookup),
    r,IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(l,s)),yes,no),
    r)


Replace the last r with any other variable (e.g. s or l) to see what it holds.

EDIT

To compare only digits, you can use the following.

=LET(source,A2:A17,lookup,C2:C11,yes,"PAID",no,"Not yet paid",
   GetDigits,LAMBDA(array,MAP(array,LAMBDA(m,
       CONCAT(TOCOL(--MID(m,SEQUENCE(LEN(m)),1),2))))),
   IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(GetDigits(lookup),GetDigits(source))),yes,no))


In More Detail
=LET(source,A2:A17,lookup,C2:C11,yes,"PAID",no,"Not yet paid",
   GetDigits,LAMBDA(array,MAP(array,LAMBDA(m,
       CONCAT(TOCOL(--MID(m,SEQUENCE(LEN(m)),1),2))))),
   s,GetDigits(source),
   l,GetDigits(lookup),
   r,IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(l,s)),yes,no),
   r)


Replace the last r with any other variable (e.g. s or l) to see what it holds.


With just a minor variation:
=LAMBDA(my_num, ora_num,
    IF(
        ISBLANK(my_num),
        "",
        IF(
            ISNUMBER(
                XMATCH(
                    TRIM(TEXTAFTER(my_num, "-", , , , my_num)),
                    TRIM(TEXTAFTER(ora_num, "-", , , , ora_num))
                )
            ),
            "PAID",
            "Not Yet Paid"
        )
    )
)(C2:C17, A2:A17)

